# How to generate barcode128 of given width and height using iTextsharp 4.1.6.0

Tags: itext

I want to create pdf of labels with barcode. below are requirments fro barcode from client.

> Format    Code 128A
>
> Height    Greater than 0.25" (6.3 mm), or 15% of the barcode length.
>
> Narrow barcode element    The specification depends on your printer's
>   resolution.
>
> For 300 dpi: 13.33 mils (.3386 mm)
>
> For 200 dpi: 20 mils (.508 mm)
>
> Wide-to-narrow element ratio  3:1
>
> Quiet zone (sides)    Greater than 0.25" (6.4 mm)
>
> Quiet zone (top and bottom)   Greater than 0.125" (3.2 mm)

And they also have requirement for each label size as,

> Use a label with a height by width dimension from 1" x 2" (2.5 cm x
>   5.0 cm) up to 2" x 3" (5.1 cm x 7.6 cm). For example, you could use a label that is 1" x 3" (2.5 cm x 7.6 cm) or 2" x 2" (5.1 cm x 5.1 cm),
>   as long as all of the required information is included.

I am trying to generate barcode using iTextSharp 4.1.6.0. but I could not set MinWidth and MaxWidth, Quiet zone for Barcode so I can fit my barcode in required size.
I can't control the width of barcode but I can control the height of barcode as

```
Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
code128.CodeType = Barcode.CODE128;
code128.Font = null;
code128.Code = “12345678910”;
code128.X = 1.1f;
code128.BarHeight = (code128.BarcodeSize.Width) * (float)(0.15);
```

Thank you
Raj

Comment: Please read [the iText FAQ](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5). The version you are using is no longer supported. You should tell your employer to stop using it.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, This library released under the Mozilla Public License and the LGPL, before the project moved to the AGPL. You can use this version if you need a free PDF library for use in closed-source projects.
https://github.com/schourode/iTextSharp-LGPL
and please correct if I wrong. and also Can you please suggest. free Library of iTextSharp.

Comment: That information is outdated. It was put there by someone who isn't affiliated to iText: [Jørn Schou-Rode](https://github.com/schourode). Please contact Jørn to find out if he did an IP review on the code there. If he didn't, I suggest that you stop using the version he has put on Github. Who do you think has the most accurate information: the creators of iText or some unknown third party? iText 7 for .NET is free on condition that you respect the AGPL. It's only fair that you have to buy a license if you want to make money yourself.

Comment: @Raj if you really want to compile iText 4.1.6 .NET, then you are perfectly able to do that from the *official* github repository. Because the repository you linked is not a fork from the official repository, you have to be extra careful that the repository really contains what it claims to contain.